# Yes to all overwrites in interactive mv/cp/rm?

Tags: command-line

So I've aliased the commands rm/cp/mv to use interactive (-i) mode by default to avoid accidentally deleting things, but sometimes this is pretty inconvenient.

I would like to be able to say 'y' to all the prompts of the form:

```
mv: overwrite `file_1'? y 
mv: overwrite `file_2'? y
```

without typing 'y' many many times.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I do not understand what you exatly want. Please edit your answer to describe it more (what you tried to do and what you really expected)

Answer (score 9):

Use `command mv` to circumvent the alias and use `--force` if that doesn't stop `mv` from bothering you with questions (e.g., because of permissions).

`yes | aCommand` is the standard way to supply lots of `y`'s to `aCommand`, but in this case that seems unnecessary.

Comment: So I can't do this "interactively", i.e. use mv -i and then once it starts prompting me, tell is "yes to all"?

Comment: This kind of thing is generally quite hard to do unless the program directly supports it (and I believe mv doesn't support this). Cancelling the action (Ctrl-C) and starting from scratch tends to be easier.

Comment: agree that you can't switch horses in the middle of the stream. Another solution like `command mv`, is to use  the full path you the cmd. i.e. `/bin/mv files ...` when you want to skip the `-i` part. Good luck.

Answer (score 5):

you can use back slash before cp

```
\cp -rf /from/directory/* to/directory
```